# Javascript display form before onclick function also

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In this case, I have defined on-click function to display the simple two form.

**Help me on**

How can I always display first form (displayRed function form) before onclick function .

```
<button onclick="displayRed()" value="11">Red</button>
<button onclick="displayBlue()" value="22">Blue</button>
<div id="flight"></div>

function displayRed() {
  document.getElementById("flight").innerHTML = "<form> <input type='text' value='1'/> </form>";
}

function displayBlue() {
  document.getElementById("flight").innerHTML = "<form> <input type='text' value='2'/> </form>";
}
```

Comment: Making `displayRed` `self-invoke`, doesn't help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your body element:

```
<body onload="displayRed()">
  <!-- everything else ...
```

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body#Attributes):

> **onload**
>   Function to call when the document has finished loading.

So by adding the onload attribute to your body element you execute that javascript function as soon as the page is loaded.

```js
function displayRed() {
  alert("Red!");
}

function displayBlue() {
  alert("Blue!");
}
```

```html
<body onload="displayRed()">
  <button onclick="displayRed()" value="11">Red</button>
  <button onclick="displayBlue()" value="22">Blue</button>
  <div id="flight"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="displayForm('red')" value="11">Red</button>
<button onclick="displayForm('blue')" value="22">Blue</button>
<div id="flight">
    <form id="myRedForm"><input type="text" value="red"></form>
</div>

<script>
    var displayForm = (function(activeForm){
        var currentForm = activeForm;
        var forms = {
            red: '<form id="myRedForm"><input type="text" value="red"></form>',
            blue: '<form id="myBlueForm"><input type="text" value="blue"></form>'
        };
        return function (formType) {
            if(formType !== activeForm) {
                document.getElementById("flight").innerHTML = forms[formType];
                currentForm = formType;
            }
        }
    })('red');
</script>
```